# How to add 28 to the value in each cell of a column? The values in each cell of the column are dates

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I copy from one sheet and paste onto another sheet at specific location. I want the values of the column on the new sheet to have 28 added to their existing value. These values are dates.

This is what I have so far. Not sure where to insert the addition. Is there a way to do this without a loop? Since I can copy the range exactly, perhaps there is an easier way to do this.

```
endRowDevelopment = wsOut.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set r1 = ws.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(endRowSheet1, 1))

r1.Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("A" & endRowDevelopment + 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For no looping, you can use teylin answer. But looping should not take that much time unless you have an extraordinary amount of data. If you can accept looping, here is a possible solution incorporating your previous question.

```
Sub test()

Set ws = Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")

endRowSheet1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsOut = Application.Worksheets("Load File")

With ws

Set r1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(endRowSheet1, 1))
    r1.Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("A2")

Set r2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(endRowSheet1, 6))
    r2.Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("E2")

End With

endRowDevelopment = wsOut.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    r1.Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("A" & endRowDevelopment + 1)
    r2.Copy Destination:=wsOut.Range("E" & endRowDevelopment + 1)

'--- adding 28 to the pasted ranges

With wsOut
    Set r3 = .Range(.Cells(endRowDevelopment + 1, "A"), .Cells(endRowDevelopment + endRowSheet1 - 1, "A"))
    Set r4 = .Range(.Cells(endRowDevelopment + 1, "E"), .Cells(endRowDevelopment + endRowSheet1 - 1, "E"))
End With

    For Each rngCell In r3.Cells
        rngCell.Value = rngCell.Value + 28
    Next rngCell

    For Each rngCell In r4.Cells
        rngCell.Value = rngCell.Value + 28
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Sometimes, what appears as "no looping" in the code actually is a loop when excel compiles the code. The only way to know what is more efficient is to write different codes and time them. In this case looping may be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a helper cell that you set with a value, copy the cell, and then use Paste Special with the Add option to add the copied value to all specified cells.

```
Range("E1") = 28
Range("E1").Copy

Range("A1:A10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
Range("E1").ClearContents
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have two equal ranges, you could likely use a formula to do this. (Adjust the ranges as necessary)

```
Sub copy_add_amt()
Dim copyRng As Range, destRng As Range
Set copyRng = Range("A1:A6")
Set destRng = Range("B1:B6")
destRng.Formula = "=" & copyRng.Address & "+28"
End Sub
```

[image]